# Rename dataframes in a list using a key

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframe and many of the columns will need to be renamed. It will be optimal to setup a key that I can use to rename the dataframe. The variables in the dataframe may or may not exist. I have been looking if there is a function that already do this but have not been able to find anything. The following example shows what I am trying to do.

```
# This is a dummy list with dataframes that may contain common variables
data_list <- list(
  dfx1 <- mtcars,
  dfx2 <- mtcars %>% rename(`mpg.1` = mpg, `cyl2` = cyl),
  dfx3 <- mtcars %>% rename(`mpg.11` = mpg),
  dfx4 <- mtcars %>% select(-mpg)
)

# Setup a key; the key does not have to be in this format
mykey <- c(
  mpg = c("mpg.1", "mpg.11"),
  cyl = c("cyl2")
)

# Is there a function that I can use to rename based in this key
lapply(x, fun, mykey)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library( data.table )
#sample data
dt1 <- data.table( x = 1, yy = 2 )
dt2 <- data.table( xx = 1, yy = 2 )
L <- list(dt1, dt2)

#actual code renaming columns from old >> new
lapply( L, function(x) setnames( x, old = c("xx", "yy"), new = c("x", "y"), skip_absent = TRUE ) )
 
# [[1]]
#    x y
# 1: 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
#    x y
# 1: 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `map` to loop over the `list`, subset the 'mykey' with the intersecting column names from the `list` element ('nm1')  If the `length` of 'mykey' is greater than 0, then rename the columns with `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data_list2 <- map(data_list, ~ {
        i1 <- mykey %in% names(.x)
        nm1 <- mykey[i1]
        if(length(nm1) >0) .x %>% 
                 rename_at(vars(nm1), ~ names(nm1)) else .x
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [wimpel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6356278/wimpel) works better for my case.

However, the key will need to be defined as a list instead of the definition in the original post.

```
mykey <- list(
  mpg = c("mpg.1", "mpg.11"),
  cyl = c("cyl2")
)
```

It can be easily implemented in function (something like):

```
rename_dfx <- function(dfx, key) {
  length_of_old <- lapply(key, length)
  newvars <- names(key)
  old_vars <- unlist(key)
  new_vars <- rep(newvars, times = unlist(length_of_old))
  
  setnames(dfx, old = old_vars, new = new_vars, skip_absent = TRUE)
  
  dfx
  
}

rename_dfx(data_list[[1]], mykey)
rename_dfx(data_list[[2]], mykey)
lapply(data_list, rename_dfx, key = mykey)
```